# Problems running FreeBSD package installation command

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to install some software on a FreeBSD 10 system. I'm not a regular FreeBSD user, so I'm not familiar with its quirks. I only have it to test building and running software.

I performed a `man -k` to see what the candidates are:

```
su -
...

man -k install
...
pkg-add(8)
```

I'm superficially familiar with other BSDs, so `pkg-add` looks about right:

```
# pkg-add bash
pkg-add: command not found
# find / -name pkg-add
#
```

Where is `pkg-add` on FreeBSD systems?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `pkg_add`. Note that you have used `-` not `_`. By the way, there are more interesting ways to install softwares, for example from source.

If you have `port` system (it's there by default) and want to install `wget`, you can just ask your FreeBSD: `whereis wget`, and it gives you something like `/usr/ports/ftp/wget`. What you must do is to `cd /usr/ports/ftp/wget`, and run `make install clean` or `make -DBATCH install clean` (if you don't like to be bothered by configurations).

Edit: It's only `pkg` in FreeBSD 10. you can use `pkg add ...`.

Edit 2: Useful (and brief) information about `pkg`, `pkg_add` and `pkgng`  tools is here: https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/10.0-RELEASE/usr/local/share/doc/freebsd/handbook/pkgng-intro.html

Comment: I'm fairly certain it `pkg-add` with the hyphen. Checkout the output from `man -k`. Also, shouldn't `port` show up in the search of the man pages? I'll try to use `port`, but I'm trying to understand what's broken with FreeBSD's docs.

Comment: FreeBSD website has a very good search. Check this out: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html
You are right about `find`, it must find it within ports. However pkg-add, and pkg_add are not included in FreeBSD 10.
Simply use `pkg add`.

Comment: This answer can be improved by pointing to _[The Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/10.0-RELEASE/usr/local/share/doc/freebsd/handbook/ports.html)_.

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP, more or less every needed information is here: https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/10.0-RELEASE/usr/local/share/doc/freebsd/handbook/pkgng-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

To install a package from a remote repository, use `pkg install` as root. (The `pkg add` command is for installing already downloaded packages.)